Placing a rectangle on top of a progress bar in TKinter
I am having problems with Tkinter. I want to place a semi transparent rectangle on top of my progress bar (rectangle will be replaced by a picture).
The idea is, that I have a graph corresponding to a video. Having the graph be semi transparent and the progress bar be visible behind it will make it possible to see the position on the graph according to the video time.
In the provided code is a method which enables rectangles to be semi transparent. The red rectangle is on top of the blue one, but the blue rectangle is still visible due to the transparency.
However I can not get it to work with my video bar. The video bar is always in the foreground and obstructs the rectangles.
Is it even possible to have the progress bar in the background and a semi transparent picture on top of it? I tried many approaches but could not get anything to work. Hopefully someone has an idea or can confirm that this is not possible.
Example of what i want to achieve:

Current code which shows transparency only working on other rectangles but not progress bar.

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import customtkinter
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.images = []  # Define images list as an attribute

        # configure window
        self.title("")
        self.geometry(f"{1280}x{720}")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        # Create a canvas
        self.canvas = customtkinter.CTkCanvas(width=400, height=200)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # thick progress bar
        self.progress_bar_style = ttk.Style()
        self.progress_bar_style.theme_use('default')
        self.progress_bar_style.configure("Custom.Horizontal.TProgressbar", thickness=50)

        self.progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal", length=500, mode="determinate", style="Custom.Horizontal.TProgressbar")
        self.progress_bar_window = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor='nw', window=self.progress_bar)

        # Draw elements on the canvas
        self.draw_elements()

    def draw_elements(self):
        self.create_rectangle(10, 10, 200, 100, fill='blue')
        self.create_rectangle(110, 20, 310, 110, fill='red', alpha=0.5)

    def create_rectangle(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs):
        if 'alpha' in kwargs:
            alpha = int(kwargs.pop('alpha') * 255)
            fill = kwargs.pop('fill')
            fill = self.canvas.winfo_rgb(fill) + (alpha,)
            image = Image.new('RGBA', (x2 - x1, y2 - y1), fill)
            self.images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(image))
            self.canvas.create_image(x1, y1, image=self.images[-1], anchor='nw')
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs)
        else:
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

I dont post often on stack overflow, so I apologize if this question is poorly structured.
I would still appreciate any help or conformation that this i not possible.
Thank you

Widget put into a canvas always has higher z-order than other canvas items.  Use rectangle item to simulate a progress bar.

Thank you for your suggestion. I now made a custom video bar, using rectangles which continously get updated. Your advice was most welcome and solved my problem.
